# Is there documentation on the Safecracker object argument on the safecracker_submit_entry_start/_end callback function?

Tags: safecracker, extension

I am using an extension that uses the hook "safecracker_submit_entry_start" and "safecracker_submit_entry_end".

The function that handles the callback has a safecracker object argument.

I am wondering if there was any documentation about what that object does.

I would like to do some things with the safecracker form data and I was wondering if this object has the methods/variables to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no documentation that I am aware of. I usually open the `safecracker/libraries/Safecracker_lib.php` and reference the class itself. The object can be seen pretty plainly this way so you know all the available methods and properties.

I can almost bet that there is a way to do what you want. You can use the hooks in Safecracker to do just about anything. You can even take a look at my Safecracker Registration extension to see how I manipulated the object.

If you have any more questions, just open another thread about the specific task you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I see. I will into that file.

Comment: It seems that there is a method, get_field_data(). But when I tried it, it looks like it returns the data about the field, not the actual data.

Comment: What data are you trying to get specifically? The value of a field from the entry you are editing?